# Using [bbox] and [extents] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have tags for:

- [bbox](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bbox) which has 32 questions and a tag wiki which says:

> bbox is a shortened form of bounding box

- [extents](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extents) which has 543 questions and a tag wiki which says:

> An extent is the minimum bounding box/rectangle (xmin, ymin and xmax,
>   ymax) defined by coordinate pairs of a data source. All coordinates
>   for the data source fall within this boundary.

The [only (and accepted) answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/240982/115) to [Difference between bounding box, envelope, extent, bounds?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/240979/115) suggests the terms are very similar.

Do we need both tags, and if not, which should be made a synonym of the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not rare that tags which have different meanings in the real world, are still used interchangeably in (GIS) Stack Exchange. Moreover, in this particular case, concepts of [bbox](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bbox) and [extents](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extents) are closely related.

Therefore, I suggest they to be synonymized and after some time, merged. This is to facilitate searching questions and to avoid duplicates. That is what tags are for.